# creating a text file through python?

Tags: python, file, text

I am trying to make my program locate a flower within a text file. The file tells the user how many flowers of that type are in stock. I can make it do this by printing the information, but is there any way the computer can put the information into a new text file first and then print the text file?

Here is the text file which contains the flowers and their stock level (and some other numbers to do with how many need to be in stock)

```
cacti,  7,  10,  5
roses,  15,  20,  20
tulips,  4,  10,  5
lilies,  9,  15,  7
```

Here is the program I have so far, which only prints what i need to find instead of making a new text file:

```
stockfile=open("stockfile.txt", "r")

print("Flower Shop") 
print("cacti, roses, tulips, or lilies?") 
flower=input("Which type of flower do you need to know the stock level of?")    
line=stockfile.readline() 
data=line.split(",") 
if flower == "cacti":
    print("Cacti" , data[0])
    print("Cacti in stock: ", data[1])
    print("Target stock level", data[2])
    print("Reorder level", data[3])
```

Comment: Because you wrote it to `print` instead of writing to a text file. Why would you be surprised that that's what it does?

Comment: You don't `stockfile.write()` any where in your code - Hence why it isn't writing.

Comment: Take a look, help yourself: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: I have wrote it to print but i just don't know how i would write it to a text file?

Comment: Then have you considered doing some research on that? *"python write to file"* gets about 11.5 million hits on Google, have you tried reading a few of those?

Answer (score 0):

A quick comment to get you started: .write() is the method for writing to file. And when opening a file, do it in a context to keep everything clean. example:

```
with open("outfile.txt","w") as fout:
    #do your stuff and write it out
    fout.write(<data>)
```

For your case you can to everything in a loop, of course. For instance:

```
with open("stockfile.txt","r") as fin:
    with open("outfile.txt","w") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            #do your stuff and write it out
            fout.write(<data>)
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score -1):

You can open a new file object as follows

```
fileObject = open('newfile.txt', 'w')
```

Write the required result in to the file and print from there as you do for the first file.

```
fileObject.write("Cacti : {}, In stock: {}, Target stock level: {}, Reorder level".format(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]))
```

Comment: `"a+"` means it appends to a file if it exists, and also opens for read as well. None of which is necessary for populating a new file from scratch (which should be mode `"w"`).

Comment: Right. I added append mode in case the file had to be edited during next runs. Thank you.